# how to get date from datetime format-python

Tags: python

how can i extract the date only without the time in same row of my csv files?

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
with open('mar.csv','rb') as csvfile:

    reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    reader.next()
    d = datetime(row[35] for row in reader)
    print(d.strftime("%Y %m %d"))
```

Example of the column:

```
8/9/2014 14:44
8/9/2014 14:44
8/12/2014 14:54
8/12/2014 10:56
8/9/2014 20:03
8/12/2014 16:09
8/12/2014 10:13
8/12/2014 23:31
8/13/2014 21:31
8/12/2014 15:44
8/12/2014 15:47
8/11/2014 9:45



TypeError: an integer is required
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has other problems beyond the one in the Q's subject, but anyway here's one clean approach to do what you ask + something of what you don't ask but need...:

```
for row in reader:
    dt = datetime.strptime(row[35], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
    d = date(year=dt.year, month=dt.month, day=dt.day)
    print(d.strftime("%Y %m %d"))
```

Alternatively,

```
    d = dt.date()
```

will work fine (and faster) if you find it readable enough for your purposes.

Comment: datetime's are annoying! Good solution!